# A object returned for public uint256 instead of integer when calling a contract getter

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethers.js

My app calls a public method to retrieve `value` from a contract with `ethers 5.1`. Here is the code:

```
                let contractValue = await contract_forsale.value();  //value is a public getter
                console.log("contractValue in deal : ", contractValue); //<<==an object returned
                console.log("escrow is : ", escrow);  //<<==33
                console.log(" contractValue != escrow ", contractValue != escrow)  //<<==false
```

Here is the console output:

```
 contractValue in deal :  {"hex": "0x21", "type": "BigNumber"}  //<<==shall be 33. why obj is returned???
 LOG  escrow is :  33  
 LOG   contractValue != escrow  false  //<<== false???
```

I don't quite understand why the returned is an object instead of an integer. Here `contractValue != escrow` is `false` in log output and this is confusing. Since `contractValue` returned is an object and `escrow` is integer `33` and they shall not equal (true from the evaluation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem many encounter when dealing with Ethereum is the concept of numbers. Most common currencies are broken down with very little granularity. For example, there are only 100 cents in a single dollar. However, there are 1018 wei in a single ether.

JavaScript uses [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers to represent numeric values. As a result, there are holes in the integer set after 9,007,199,254,740,991; which is problematic for Ethereum because that is only around 0.009 ether (in wei), which means any value over that will begin to experience rounding errors.

To demonstrate how this may be an issue in your code, consider:

```
(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2 - 2) == (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
// false
```

To remedy this, all numbers (which can be large) are stored and manipulated as [BigNumbers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/).

The functions [`parseEther(etherString)`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther) and [`formatEther(wei)`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-formatEther) can be used to convert between string representations, which are displayed to or entered by the user and Big Number representations which can have mathematical operations handled safely.

#### Comparing BigNumbers

Since when you compare objects in JavaScript, it compares the reference. That's why instead of `contractValue == escrow`, you can do `contractValue.eq(escrow)`. For `!=` you can `!contractValue.eq(escrow)`.

For more methods, you can check out the [docs here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--methods).

Comment: `Soham Zemse`, very interesting. Can I treat the bigNumber returned from contract as an integer and use it as value for an object key or perform math op with it?

Comment: Thoguh you could do `bigNumberValue.toNumber()` but it will error if value is greater than `2^53 - 1` (which is `0.009 ether`). If you want to do some math, you have to use helper methods like `bigNumberValue.mul(2)`. You can checkout the docs link at the last of the answer